# Java - How to calculate the first and last day of each week

Tags: java, calendar

I'm trying to create a weekly calendar that looks like this: http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/sample_basic.html

How can I calculate every week date? For example, this week is:

> Monday - Sunday
>   7 June, 8 June, 9 June, 10 June, 11 June, 12 June, 13 June

Comment: I don't understand where is the problem. Try to reword the question.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I guess this does what you want:

```
// Get calendar set to current date and time
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

// Set the calendar to monday of the current week
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

// Print dates of the current week starting on Monday
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE dd/MM/yyyy");
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    System.out.println(df.format(c.getTime()));
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I want, if i want previous button can get last week date any idea?

Comment: Class `Calendar` contains methods for date arithmetic. To move it back a week (7 days), do `c.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);`, for example.

Comment: Thank You very much appreaciate your help .

Comment: Instead of hardcoding Calendar.MONDAY as the first day of the week, you should use `Calendar#getFirstDayOfWeek()` instead, since the scope of a week is locale dependent.

Comment: However, your code simply _does not work reliably_. See my comment below and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722542 for an explanation.

Comment: jarnbjo, I love you! You solved my bug! I wanna buy you a beer.

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). See [Answer by Przemek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33868624/642706).

Answer (score 13):

With the new date and time API in Java 8 you would do:

```
LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

// determine country (Locale) specific first day of current week
DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).getFirstDayOfWeek();
LocalDate startOfCurrentWeek = now.with(TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame(firstDayOfWeek));

// determine last day of current week
DayOfWeek lastDayOfWeek = firstDayOfWeek.plus(6); // or minus(1)
LocalDate endOfWeek = now.with(TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame(lastDayOfWeek));

// Print the dates of the current week
LocalDate printDate = startOfCurrentWeek;
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEE dd/MM/yyyy");
for (int i=0; i < 7; i++) {
    System.out.println(printDate.format(formatter));
    printDate = printDate.plusDays(1);
}
```

Answer (score 10):

## Java.time

Using `java.time` library built into Java 8:

```
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.previousOrSame;
import static java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame;

LocalDate now = LocalDate.now(); # 2015-11-23
LocalDate first = now.with(previousOrSame(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)); # 2015-11-23
LocalDate last = now.with(nextOrSame(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY)); # 2015-11-29
```

You can iterate over `DayOfWeek.values()` to get all current week days

```
DayOfWeek.values(); # Array(MONDAY, TUESDAY, WEDNESDAY, THURSDAY, FRIDAY, SATURDAY, SUNDAY)
for (DayOfWeek day: DayOfWeek.values()) {
    System.out.print(first.with(nextOrSame(day)));
} # 2015-11-23, 2015-11-24, 2015-11-25, 2015-11-26, 2015-11-27, 2015-11-28, 2015-11-29
```

Answer (score 9):

First day of this week.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    while (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.MONDAY) {
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
    }
```

Comment: It's not necessary to step back to Monday day by day, you can just `c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);` to set the calendar to Monday of the current week (see my answer).

Comment: Absolutely not, @Jesper. Setting the day of the week does not necessarily move backwards.

Comment: Simple and elegant solution!

Answer (score 6):

Simply setting the day of week does not seem to be reliable. Consider the following simple code:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
calendar.set(2011, Calendar.SEPTEMBER, 18);
System.out.printf("Starting day: %tF%n", calendar);

calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
System.out.printf("Last monday: %tF%n", calendar);
System.out.printf("First day of week: %d%n", calendar.getFirstDayOfWeek());
```

The result of running this program is:

```
Starting day: 2011-09-18
Last monday: 2011-09-19
First day of week: 2
```

In other words, it stepped forward in time. For a German locale, this is really not the expected answer. Note that the calendar correctly uses Monday as first day of the week (only for computing the week of the year, perhaps).

Answer (score 2):

You can build up on this: The following code prints the first and last dates of each week for 15 weeks from now.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
for(int i=0; i<15; i++)
{
    System.out.print("Start Date : " + c.getTime() + ", ");
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 6);
    System.out.println("End Date : " + c.getTime());
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know which day it is (Friday) and the current date (June 11), you can calculate the other days in this week.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you use [Joda](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) Time library. Gregorian Calendar class has weekOfWeekyear and dayOfWeek methods.

Answer (score 1):

```
    Calendar startCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    startCal.setTimeInMillis(startDate);
    Calendar endCal = Calendar.getInstance();
    endCal.setTimeInMillis(endDate);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMMM-yyyy");
    while (startCal.before(endCal)) {
        int weekNumber = startCal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
        cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNumber);
        Date sunday = cal.getTime();
        Log.d("sunday", "" + sdf.format(sunday));
        cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SATURDAY);
        cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNumber);
        Date saturday = cal.getTime();
        Log.d("saturday", "" + sdf.format(saturday));
        weekNumber = weekNumber + 1;
        startCal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, weekNumber);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm you're looking for (calculating the day of the week for any given date) is "Zeller's Congruence".  Here's a Java implementation:

http://technojeeves.com/joomla/index.php/free/57-zellers-congruence

Comment: theres another implementation @ http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/zellers-congruence-in-java". Though as mentioned in that post your better off using the Calendar class - http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/use-calendar-class-to-get-localized-day-names, which can also be used to get the first day of the week - http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-do-i-get-the-date-of-first-day-of-the-current-week

Answer (score -1):

Yes.  Use Joda Time

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/