# Does the setMonth method of Java Calendar work wrong?

Tags: java, calendar

I have small code such as below. I expected that the result should be `7`, but it printed `6`. If I uncomment the line `tmp.get(Calendar.MONTH)`, it runs OK (prints `7`).

Please let me know the reason. I'm using JDK 1.7.0_25 in MacOS.

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Calendar tmp = Calendar.getInstance();
    tmp.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);
    tmp.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
    //tmp.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    tmp.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    System.out.println(tmp.get(Calendar.MONTH));
}
```

Screenshot: 
Comment code: http://gyazo.com/4c099b1b2b90d72d1954b98b134e4ac3 
Uncomment code: http://gyazo.com/fe368745da168646140ca9f3a60d2021

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722542/java-calendar-date-is-unpredictable-after-setting-day-of-week

Answer (score 3):

Because month index starts with index 0. add +1 while get month. it is c based structure copied into java. It has indexes 0 to 11.

And i think day of month is incorrect. comment that and run it it shows correctly.(`tmp.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);`)

```
    tmp.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);
    tmp.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.AUGUST);
    //tmp.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    //tmp.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
    System.out.println(tmp.get(Calendar.MONTH));
```

By default it takes year as 2015 and August 4 is `tuesday` not `monday`

Comment: But the August is 8, after minus 1, we should have 7. Right?

Comment: I've already known it. So if I change the date of week to monday, it will be moved to the last  monday, so it should be Monday August 03. And the last result is 7.

Comment: it will override the month set by 2 line of code. have a look on source code.

Answer (score 2):

I tried to run your code and it prints 7 every time (even tried to uncomment that line you mention). Which seems correct to me.

**EDIT** The problem is explained in detail [Java Calendar - Date is unpredictable after setting day_of_week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722542/java-calendar-date-is-unpredictable-after-setting-day-of-week)

I am glad that with Java 8 came new API for working with date and time.

**EDIT2**

My understanding of what happened:

Only sensible combinations are

```
YEAR + MONTH + DATE (let's call it A)
```

or

```
YEAR + MONTH + WEEK_OF_MONTH + DAY_OF_WEEK (let's call it B)
```

And the Calendar has its inner state of date in which he thinks he is. So basically before you set

```
DAY_OF_WEEK
```

you were working with combination A but after it you were working with combination B and this line

```
tmp.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 4);
```

was ignored. Thus it took Monday in the first week of August (2015-07-27). But when you called

```
tmp.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

you "materialized" the date according to combination A (so to 2015-08-04) and the

```
DAY_OF_WEEK
```

was set "correctly" starting from 2015-08-04.

Anyway could you try that with JDK 8?

Comment: Thanks! I'm thinking about JDK or OS version. That's the reason I share my OS and JDK in question.

Comment: Could you add System.out.println(tmp.get(Calendar.MONTH) + ": " + tmp.getTime()); to your code? It would be interesting to see what is your final date then.

Comment: Result with comment the get function: http://gyazo.com/4c099b1b2b90d72d1954b98b134e4ac3 (6 --- Mon Jul 27 17:33:12 ICT 2015 )

And uncomment it: 
http://gyazo.com/fe368745da168646140ca9f3a60d2021
(7 --- Mon Aug 03 17:31:23 ICT 2015 )

Answer (score 1):

When you set DAY_OF_WEEK = MONDAY, Calendar returns back to last Monday and it is 27th of Jul, you can check it with `System.out.println(tmp.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));`

Comment: August/04 is Tuesday. So last Monday should be August/03

Answer (score 0):

#### Avoid pre-Java-8 Date and Calendar

> [The existing Java date and time classes are poor, mutable, and have
>   unpredictable performance.](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/150)

This applies somehow equally to Calendar, which has some of the same problems. [Weaknesses of Calendar](http://www.heise.de/developer/artikel/Die-neue-Date-Time-API-in-Java-8-2198399.html) (german link) are

- not really a calendar, but date + time
- mutable
- January is `0`th month, not `1`st
- unintuitive API: you have to use `get(Calendar.HOUR)` instead of `getHour`
- ...

#### if you are using Java <8, use Joda-Time

In the comments to [java-calendar-date-is-unpredictable-after-setting-day-of-week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722542/java-calendar-date-is-unpredictable-after-setting-day-of-week), [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html) is recommended as an alternative by @JonSkeet, as it is by those folks of the [JDK Enhancement Proposal](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/150). Your code could look like

```
import org.joda.time.MutableDateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    MutableDateTime tmp = new MutableDateTime();
    tmp.setDayOfMonth(4);
    tmp.setMonthOfYear(8);
    tmp.setDayOfWeek(1);

    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.fullDate();
    System.out.println(fmt.print(tmp));
    }
}
```

#### Immutable

There is also the [immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214714/mutable-vs-immutable-objects) [DateTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class, [which you **will** want to use instead](http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/09/objects-should-be-immutable.html). (immutability adds several positive effects, in Java 8 it is [the default](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html))

```
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.fullDate();

        DateTime tmp = new DateTime().withDayOfMonth(4).withMonthOfYear(8);
        System.out.println(fmt.print(tmp));

        tmp = tmp.withDayOfWeek(1);
        System.out.println(fmt.print(tmp));
    }
}
```

#### If on Java-8,

the `java.time` API is based on Joda-Time. Use

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME;

        LocalDateTime tmp
            = LocalDateTime.now().withDayOfMonth(4).withMonthOfYear(8);
        System.out.println(fmt.format(tmp));

        tmp = tmp.withDayOfWeek(1);
        System.out.println(fmt.format(tmp));
    }
}
```

(I have not tested the Java-8 version)

Answer (score 0):

When you set the day of week, Calendar has no way to know what you expect. If you expect to get the date of another day of the same week, you should set the week of year too to indicate which week you expect.