# Get next week and previous week staring and ending dates in java

Tags: java, date, calendar, dayofweek

I want to get the starting and ending dates of a week
for example

2012-05-06 to 2012-05-12 
2012-05-13 to 2012-05-19

The code I have written is

```
currWeekCalender.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, 1);

    String dateStart =  currWeekCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + addZero((currWeekCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)) + "-" + addZero(currWeekCalender.getFirstDayOfWeek());
    currWeekCalender.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,7);
    String dateEnd =  currWeekCalender.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + addZero((currWeekCalender.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1)) + "-" + addZero(currWeekCalender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
```

but the results are not correct, also I want previous weeks date.

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "not correct"? What are you seeing, and what do you expect to see? Also, that's not how to get a String from a Date object. Use a SimpleDateFormat object for this.

Comment: See [java-how-to-calculate-the-first-and-last-day-of-each-week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023267/java-how-to-calculate-the-first-and-last-day-of-each-week) Also take a look at [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/userguide.html), which simplifies working with dates and times in Java.

Comment: @kaibuki can you get any solution becuase same thing i required..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java - How to calculate the first and last day of each week](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023267/java-how-to-calculate-the-first-and-last-day-of-each-week). And do some searching for other similar questions with helpful answers and example code, including all those "Related" items listed on the lower right (if viewing this in web browser).

Comment: Tip: For handling a span of time (a week), see the `Interval` class in Joda-Time and similar class in java.time package in Java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `getFirstDayOfWeek()` returns the first day of the week; e.g., Sunday in US, Monday in France.  It does not return a day of the month.  See [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#getFirstDayOfWeek()).

The first day in a month that is the start of the week is (in pseudo-code)

```
((7 + (firstDayOfWeek - dayOfWeek(firstOfMonth))) % 7) + 1
```

You can translate that into `java.util.Calendar` code if you like, but I would suggest using Joda time instead.

---

> also I want previous weeks date.

Just subtract seven days maybe using [`add`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#add%28int,%20int%29)

```
currCalendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7)
```

This may involve underflow, but `add` deals with that.

> #### `add(f, delta)`
>
> adds delta to field f. This is equivalent to calling `set(f, get(f) + delta)` with two adjustments:
>
> **Add rule 1.** The value of field f after the call minus the value of field f before the call is delta, modulo any overflow that has occurred in field f. Overflow occurs when a field value exceeds its range and, as a result, *the next larger field is incremented or decremented and the field value is adjusted back into its range.*

Answer (score 4):

Hello to all coders :)

I work on little app to dive some data from database. To calculate previous weeks start and end date i use this code:

```
// Calendar object
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

// "move" cal to monday this week (i understand it this way)
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

// calculate monday week ago (moves cal 7 days back)
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -7);
Date firstDateOfPreviousWeek = cal.getTime();

// calculate sunday last week (moves cal 6 days fwd)
cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 6);
Date lastDateOfPreviousWeek = cal.getTime();
```

Hope, that helps.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8 version

This prints previous 10 weeks

```
final ZonedDateTime input = ZonedDateTime.now();

for(int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
    final ZonedDateTime startOfLastWeek = input.minusWeeks(i).with(DayOfWeek.MONDAY);
    System.out.print(startOfLastWeek.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
    final ZonedDateTime endOfLastWeek = startOfLastWeek.plusDays(6);
    System.out.println(" - " + endOfLastWeek.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE));
}
```