# Country specific calendars java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, quartz-scheduler

can anyone give me pointers to a library/way of getting country specific calendars. THis is because I am looking to implement Quartz and would like to use different calendars for different countries.

THank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this ->

http://icu-project.org/docs/papers/international_calendars_in_java.html

As Joao suggested, you can use

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
```

You should also look at this

[Is there a way to get a timeZone with (only) a country code (valid ISO-3166 code)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1389837/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-timezone-with-only-a-country-code-valid-iso-3166-code)

and this

[non standard locale with java.util.Calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493976/non-standard-locale-with-java-util-calendar)

Else best is using [Joda-Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest trying Joda Time

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

, which has different Chronologies.

Comment: thanks, for telling me about such a good library.

Answer (score 1):

JodaTime is a very good api to manipulate those things.

http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/