# override first day of the week in joda?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, jodatime

Is it possible to override the firstday of Joda week to **sunday** ? since Joda uses **Monday** as its firstday of the week . 
Can any one please explain me if there is a way .

I referred the below Topic in SOF

[Joda Time: First day of week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801907/joda-time-first-day-of-week)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

First of all, overriding the first day of the week to sunday would require overwriting all other weekdays as well. But these final constants are defined in the class [DateTimeConstants](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/DateTimeConstants.html#MONDAY), which are impossible to overwrite. But you wouldn't want to override theses values anyways because it would mess up joda-time's ISO-compliance.

At the same time I wonder why you would want to override it in the first place? Can you provide a use case?

```
public static DateTime getUSFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY).minusDays(1);
}
```

This simple helper method would probably do the job. Notice that I didn't use `SUNDAY`because it would be in the future, which is - in US notion - the next week already.

Comment: Use case: what's the week number of 2006-12-31 -- 1 or 52?
More generic use case: draw a chart with two series: 1: our weekly revenue for current year, 2: weekly revenue for last year, to compare the data. For US users weeks must start on Sunday. It's pretty common in many industries.

Comment: "... because it would mess up joda-time's ISO-compliance."
But it supports custom minDaysInFirstWeek, doesn't it "mess up ISO-compliance"?

Comment: There is `ReadableDateTime#getWeekOfWeekyear()`, but this might be wrong for you since it uses monday as first day. I think you won't get around implementing a 'correct' substitute for that method for your application. About the ISO-compliance messup: shure, JodaTime supports loads of custom stuff to mess it all up--take for example complete different chronologies--but I would try to avoid that as far as possible since it may produce corrupt results when combined with other points of your joda time usage.