# Joda Time Week Ending Date

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm trying to get the last day of the week using Joda time.

Is this the correct way (production ready) to do this for Sunday - Saturday:

```
        DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/New_York" );
        DateTime now = new DateTime( timeZone );

        DateTime weekStart = now.withDayOfWeek( DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY ).minusDays(6);
        DateTime weekEnd = now.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY).plusDays( 0 );
        Interval week = new Interval( weekStart, weekEnd );
        //Dump to console…
        String[] week_start = weekStart.toString().split("T"); 
        String[] week_End = weekEnd.toString().split("T"); 
        String[] now_date = now.toString().split("T"); 
        System.out.println( "now: " + now_date[0] );
        System.out.println( "weekStart: " + week_start[0]);
        System.out.println( "weekEnd: " + week_End[0] );
        System.out.println( "week: " + week );
```

**Output:**

```
now: 2015-08-06
weekStart: 2015-08-02
weekEnd: 2015-08-08
week: 2015-08-02T14:15:46.580-04:00/2015-08-08T14:15:46.580-04:00
```

Comment: The code is fine, the week starts Monday (2015-08-03) at midnight and ends exactly one week later (2015-08-10). Why do you expect it to end on Saturday? We are talking about calendar weeks, not work weeks.

Comment: Hi, I want the start date to be sunday and end date to be saturday.

Comment: So DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY for start day and DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY for end?

Comment: You cannot override Joda start and end days of week, if thats what you want to acheive http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13602096/override-first-day-of-the-week-in-joda

Comment: That's really interesting, so they never thought this would be used for business purposes? Some businesses require Sunday through Saturday and my specific peice needs to be 100% correct. Joda time cannot do this? That's disappointing. Thank you for your link!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to `gaganbm`'s comment, I did this:

```
DateTime weekStart = getUSFirstDayOfWeek(now);
DateTime weekEnd = now.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY).plusDays( 0 );

public static DateTime getUSFirstDayOfWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
    return dateTime.withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY).minusDays(1);
}
```

Seems to produce the correct results!