# Trying to get date of Monday in current week

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have implemented a method to get the date of the Monday in the current week, and I have assigned Monday to be the first day of the week.

But, no matter what I do, it returns Sun Mar 24 15:03:07 GMT 2013. I can't see what the issue is here. Anybody able to help?

```
public static Date getFirstDayOfWeekDate()
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(2);
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
    cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    Date firstDayOfTheWeek = cal.getTime();
    return firstDayOfTheWeek;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this :

```
public static Date getFirstDayOfWeekDate() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,
            cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK));
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    int week = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    return new Date(now.getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 * (week - 1));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    c.setTime(new Date());
    int today = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, -today+Calendar.MONDAY);
    System.out.println("Date "+c.getTime());
```

Comment: This gives me the next Monday.

Answer (score 1):

Just add one to the day of the week:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, cal.getActualMinimum(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) + 1);
return cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Shortest way, but it's missing cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);

Answer (score 0):

Or with [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/)

```
LocalDate.now().withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.MONDAY);
```

From [Joda Time: First day of week?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801907/joda-time-first-day-of-week)