# How display the weeks of the month in Java

Tags: android, calendar, jodatime

I'm trying to calculate the weeks of the month but I'm very confused how can I do... (I'm using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/))

I considered, for example, current month (variable in input):

[image]

I would like see in output this result (based on Local date, possibly):

```
1 week: 03-30-2014 --- 04-05-2014
2 week: 04-06-2014 --- 04-12-2014
3 week: 04-13-2014 --- 04-19-2014
4 week: 04-20-2014 --- 04-26-2014
5 week: 04-27-2014 --- 05-03-2014
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joda Time: First day of week?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1801907/joda-time-first-day-of-week)

Comment: Get a DateTime object then call the `plusDays` or `plusWeeks` methods. Many examples on StackOverflow if you search.

Comment: Is not same case because I need to manage the previus month and the next month...

Comment: No solution with JodaTime when it comes to localized week calculations. You have to roll your own home-grown and possibly error-prone solution. Other libraries like JSR-310 in Java-8 are better (there watch out for class `WeekFields`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the link I posted in a comment, and the tip about plusDays and plusWeeks I posted as a comment, I wrote the following example using Joda-Time 2.3.

```
int month = DateTimeConstants.APRIL;
int year = 2014;
int dayOfWeek = DateTimeConstants.SUNDAY;

LocalDate firstOfMonth = new LocalDate( year, month, 1 );
LocalDate firstOfNextMonth = firstOfMonth.plusMonths( 1 );
LocalDate firstDateInGrid = firstOfMonth.withDayOfWeek( dayOfWeek );
if ( firstDateInGrid.isAfter( firstOfMonth ) ) { // If getting the next start of week instead of desired week's start, adjust backwards.
    firstDateInGrid = firstDateInGrid.minusWeeks( 1 );
}

LocalDate weekStart = firstDateInGrid;
LocalDate weekStop = null;
int weekNumber = 0;

do {
    weekNumber = weekNumber + 1;
    weekStop = weekStart.plusDays( 6 );
    System.out.println( weekNumber + " week: " + weekStart + " --- " + weekStop );  // 1 week: 03-30-2014 --- 04-05-2014
    weekStart = weekStop.plusDays( 1 );
} while ( weekStop.isBefore( firstOfNextMonth ) );
```

When run…

```
1 week: 2014-03-30 --- 2014-04-05
2 week: 2014-04-06 --- 2014-04-12
3 week: 2014-04-13 --- 2014-04-19
4 week: 2014-04-20 --- 2014-04-26
5 week: 2014-04-27 --- 2014-05-03
```

As for formatting the date string differently, you can search StackOverflow for "joda format" to find many examples.

To use a day-of-week to start the week in a localized manner, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1801907/642706). But generally it may be best to ask the user. And for the American readers, remember that the United States is in the minority with starting the week on Sunday.